# How do I verify that a collection is correctly fetched from db?

Tags: nhibernate, repository, integration-testing

I am trying to write an integration test for my repository, but I can't find a nice way to assert that the results are what I want them to.

I have a class with static properties for all my test data - Projects, Users etc. In the setup of my test, I insert all these entities in my database using NHibernate (and I've been able to verify that this works - the records are there as they should after the setup is complete).

My repository (slightly simplified) does this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetEntitiesByProjectID(id)
{
    return session.Linq<MyEntity>().Where(e => e.Project.ID == id).ToList();
}
```

In my test, I try to assert that the results are correct as in the code example below, but the collections are not equivalent for several reasons - the primary one being that referenced other entites are replaced with castle proxies (`Castle.Proxies.UserProxy` instead of `User`).

```
Assert.AreElementsEqualIgnoreOrder(
    Data.MyEntites.Where(e => e.Project.ID == 1), results)
```

There are some other oddities too - for example the way datetimes are represented. In my .NET types, the datetime string representations are `2011-07-05T14:28:11.5655935+02:00`, while the ones coming from the db are `2011-07-05T14:28:11.0000000`, i.e. without the timezone indicator.

By inspection I can verify that the repository has really fetched the right elements, so my test is obviously testing the wrong thing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure than you have to test data layer? I believe NHIbernate was well tested and you have to test you service layer and provide mocks for data.

If it's not a case, set lazy loading to false during your integration testing, it should help resolve UserProxy instead of User issue.
For datetime issue, please check what data type has a column in database, there are: datetime, datetime2, date... check if you column support timezones

Comment: Regarding testing the data layer: I tried to mock `ISession` using Microsoft Moles, but was unsuccessful in creating the NHibernate.Moles.dll (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580014/cant-generate-nhibernate-moles-dll-build-errors-in-generated-code) about it) so I've resorted to integration testing instead (although I want to do both, so mocking NHibernate doesn't solve this problem...). I'll see if I can manage to set lazy loading to false and check my datetime column datatypes and get back.

Comment: I've worked quite a lot on this now, and come to the following conclusions: 1) Turning off lazy loading solved the proxy problem. Thanks! 2) I've tried all the available datetime types in SQL Server, and none of them works. The one I've decided to use is datetime (mainly for concurrency with the rest of the application), and I've found that the two datetime instances have the exact same value for `.Ticks`, so they really represent the same point in time.